# How to use the access token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

How to use the **access token** after I get it with **javascript** ( response.authResponse.accessToken ) ?

I want that everyone can send a message to a friend ( **even after logged out from facebook** ).

EDIT:

I have just tryed this code but it doesn't work:

```
FB.api('/me?access_token=AAACZBLSe4fcoBAFcGMJZAUS9OthIr5o6ZCUySgXYj0nfWX7u08X7h0VZAFFuJJs9LmeWgud2u5ZCEZCeUHZCVIq1Y2j4gjKAjJ0gx5OY9PBihlABJn64njm', function(response) { });

function sendRequestto() {
      FB.ui({
          method: 'send',
          name: 'hello',
          to: '100000497530558',
          description: 'yuhuuuuuuu'
          });    
}
```

and in the body:

```
<input type="button" onclick="sendRequestto(); return false;" value="sendRequestto" />
```

Comment: I missed a forward slash before me. Edited my example. Just Add / before me

Comment: I get the same problem :(. alert(response.name) return "undefined".

Comment: maybe do I need to request some special permission ? From this URL, I get "The session is invalid because the user logged out" : https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token...

Comment: See this: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/#extend_token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       alert('Your name is ' + response.name);
     });
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app
  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
  }
 });
```

There is no need to use the access token explicitly. The API does that for you.

Comment: uhm, but this doesn't work if the user is offline on facebook :(

Comment: The offline usage is described nicely by vivek.

Answer (score 4):

All you have to do is to save the access_token the database/cookie/session and while calling the FB.api method, append access token to the graph url like this

```
FB.api('/me/friends?access_token=...', function(response) {
  alert(response.name);
});
```

For using the access token offline, you must get the offline_access permission or extended validity access token.

Comment: excuse me, I have just tryed your code but appears the windows to login on facebook. Could you see my code in edited post above. thanks :)