# How to get offline access with the access token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

On my simple site, people can share everything ( **even after logged out from facebook** ).

So, **I have stored the token** and the I get the long lived token. So I get this response:

```
access_token=AAACZBLSe4fcoBAEmBMbHZAtTZB6uWxdnPbFrn0GU8OZByZCAzk3zNsgCZApxRBwgef‌​kbqQQjrNYP5lpQ6ZCdG15sJ1mpIigh9G3HZBAf6z9bIQZDZD&expires=5178262 .
```

You can notice that "**expires**" parameter ( in the previous link ) contain 60x24x60x60 seconds ( 60 days ). But when I logout from facebook, I get the error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Error invalidating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190,
      "error_subcode": 467
   }
}
```

How can I get the offline access ?
.

P.s. I am using **JS SDK** but I think that this doesn't matter.

Comment: When you logout from facebook you get an error? What do you mean? Also, your token is still valid, Antonio ;-)

Comment: yes, I get the error that you can see above by using this function: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/#extend_token

Comment: Is offline_access enabled on your app settings? Since plans are in motion to deprecate it, I wonder if it has to be enabled on your app to work at all.

Comment: offline_access is not enabled on my app. So is there not a way to send message after a user is logged out from facebook ? If so, how to use the access token ?

Comment: I have not tried this, but someone brought up a similar issue on another question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435863/how-to-use-the-access-token

I guess you can just append the access token in your API calls, but again, I have not tried it.